# Any reason for using "*/" in command "ls -d */" to list directories?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I know there are some other ways to do the same thing, such as

```
ls -l | grep "^d"
```

or

```
ls -F | grep "/$"
```

I am just curious about the reason for adding `*/` after `ls -d`. Why simply using `ls -d` not work? Is there any story or tricky stuff behind it?

Comment: Did you try it without the `*/` and see what it does differently?

Comment: Simply using "ls -d" will return local directory "." only, no matter where you are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding the `-d` flag simply instructs `ls` to simply list directory entries rather than their contents. The `*` given to `ls` is expanded to all the entries in the current directory, both files and dirs.  So `ls -d *` will list all entries in this directory, without expanding the subdirectories.  But if you use `*/`, then bash expands this to only include the directories in this directory.  But with just `ls */`, all the directories will be expanded.  Adding the `-d` flag prevents that, and you get just the directories in this directory.

Comment: "-d, --directory
list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links" It is what I found in "ls"'s man. I think it is not depicted well."without expanding subdirectories" should be the real meaning.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `ls -d *`, then you will see not just directories, but also files.  If you use `ls -d */`, you will only see directories.